# SocketException when sending List<T> over WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, list, generics

As the questions states. I am unable to send `List<T>` over WCF. I cannot understand why and I have been searching high and low over the internet for the past week without any concrete answers. I keep getting a SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. However, if I call a method that only returns a string, it works without problems.

I am hosting my WCF on IIS Express 7.5. I can confirm that I can access my service via my browser or other devices on my local network via my machine's IP.

If it's of any help, I am actually following this tutorial: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/urmimalapal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/

When I attempt to call FindEmployee, I get that error. I have also created another method that simply returns a string and calling it works fine. No errors. I have tried it on my WP7 emulator, WCF Test Client and WCFStorm and they all exhibit the same problem with `List<T>` trying to be returned and string being returned with no problems. I have also confirmed the list is being populated properly when my Linq statement hits the breakpoint. It's definitely WCF refusing to send my `List<T>`.

Edit: 
This is the XML reply I'm getting from WCFStorm when I attempt to call a method that throws a `List<T>`.

> ```
> <FindVendor>
>   <MethodParameters>
>     <SocketException>
>       <ErrorCode>10054</ErrorCode>
>       <Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
>       <SocketErrorCode>ConnectionReset</SocketErrorCode>
>       <NativeErrorCode>10054</NativeErrorCode>
>       <Data>
>         <KeysAndValues attr0="KeyValuePairArray" isNull="false" />
>       </Data>
>       <InnerException isNull="true" />
>       <TargetSite>Int32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)</TargetSite>
>       <StackTrace>at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)</StackTrace>
>       <HelpLink isNull="true" />
>       <Source>System</Source>
>     </SocketException>
>   </MethodParameters>
> </FindVendor>
> ```

Comment: List of what? Are you sure the "what" is serializable? Also, some source code would be helpful to give a proper answer.

Comment: I'm following the tutorial I've linked to in my question. I've basically created the WCF service in Visual Studio and am running it on IIS Express 7.5 so I can call the service from my own machine. Oddly enough, Cassini (ASP Development Server) doesn't allow calls outside the localhost. I don't know if the tutorial is just botched or I'm doing something really wrong. I have a strong hunch it my web.config on my server. But I have no clue how to configure it. Then again, even the tutorial didn't configure the web.config. So I'm assuming it should be left alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't bothered to download any sample code associated with the tutorial, but I notice the `MyEmployee` entity is not defined in the tutorial. You should ensure that it is marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute like so:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyEmployee
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; } // etc
}
```

There is also the possiblity that you will have to declare KnownTypes to the serialiser, depending on what you are doing - you should post the piece of code, and maybe turn on [WCF logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx) to get you a better error message.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I actually forgot to set the "Serialization Mode" of my .dbml file to "Unidirectional". I thought I was going crazy when none of my sniffing with Fiddler was giving me clues. It wasn't the right answer to my problem, but it's definitely something to do with serialization.